# codeigniter form_error for array key

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form with multiple input fields with the same name. These get populated using a for loop.

```
<input type="text" id="form_dest_numb[<?=$i?>]" name="form_dest_numb[<?=$i?>]" value="<?php echo $form_dest_numb[$i];?>" maxlength="15" size="15" />
```

I am now applying validation to these fields by using the same callback function. My problem now seems to be with displayed the form errors.

I currently have the following piece of code:

```
<?php if(form_error('form_dest_numb['.$i.']')) { echo "<div class=\"error\"><span class=\"error\">" . form_error('form_dest_numb['.$i.']') . "</span></div>"; } ?>
```

I can't seem to display the error message a particular key. I want the error message to highlight the affected row in the array. Is there a way to pass the key to the form_error variable name?

Comment: how do you apply form validation? what is the filed name for form validation rules?

Comment: @ElijanSejic $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_dest_numb[]','','callback_validate_dest_numb');

Comment: check my posted answer and see how that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't unless you write your own function by extending the `Form_validation` error function (which is used by forms helper `form_error` function )

The reason that CI `error` function in this class takes argument a filed name, the filed name in a rule you set up is `$this->form_validation->set_rules('form_dest_numb[]','','callback_validate_dest_‌​numb');` So CI is looking for the errors in name `form_dest_numb[]` not in `form_dest_numb[1], form_dest_numb[1]` etc...

The other way to fix this is to set validation rules fro each filed (also using a for loop)

```
for(i=0;  $i<10; $i+2){ // +2 as example with fields not being properly indexed 

     $this->form_validation->set_rules('form_dest_numb['.$i.']','','callback_validate_dest_‌​numb');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Further to Elijan Sejic's answer, which is correct, I wrote the following functions to help with setting the validation rules, and getting the errors and values:

In MY_Form_validation.php:

```
function set_rules_array($name, $label, $rules)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST[$name]); $i++)
    {
        $this->set_rules("{$name}[$i]", $label, $rules);
    }
}
```

In a helper I'm calling `form2`:

```
function form2_error($name)
{
    static $array_fields = array();

    // if the last 2 characters are [], then handle this as an array field.
    if (substr($name, -2) === '[]')
    {
        // If this field has been form2_error'd before, then increment the index, otherwise set to zero.
        $array_fields[$name] = ! isset($array_fields[$name]) ? 0 : $array_fields[$name] + 1;
        $name = substr($name, 0, -2) . '[' . $array_fields[$name]. ']';
    }
    return form_error($name);
}

function form2_set_value($name)
{
    static $array_fields = array();

    // if the last 2 characters are [], then handle this as an array field.
    if (substr($name, -2) === '[]')
    {
        // If this field has been form2_error'd before, then increment the index, otherwise set to zero.
        $array_fields[$name] = ! isset($array_fields[$name]) ? 0 : $array_fields[$name] + 1;
        $name = substr($name, 0, -2) . '[' . $array_fields[$name]. ']';
    }
    return set_value($name);
}
```

This is particularly useful if you form has an "Add More" button and you have no idea how many array elements to expect.